# A conditional sequence number for each order in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

How to generate a sequence number with condition.

below is the input,in this `<OrderLines>`  is unbounded element inside this `<LineValue1>` is there. if `<LineValue1>` is NULL then we have to ignore this `<LineValue1>` element and don't increment sequence number.The same way as `<Item>` is child element of `<OrderLines>`.If `<ItemValue1>` is Null then we have to ignore this element and don't increment the sequence number.otherwise we have to increment sequence number. like below output.

input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<process xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/JMS_TEST/JMS_Publish/JMSSendToQueue">
   <OrderHeader><!-- unbounded -->
      <HeaderValue1>HeaderValue11063</HeaderValue1>
      <OrderLines><!-- unbounded -->
         <LineValue1>LineValue11064</LineValue1>
         <Linelevel>Linelevel1419</Linelevel>
         <Linesyb>Linesyb1420</Linesyb>
         <Item><!-- unbounded -->
            <ItemValue1></ItemValue1><!-- if ItemValue1 is  null then ignore the sequence number(don't increment) -->
            <ItemLevel>ItemLevel1422</ItemLevel>
            <Itemsyb>Itemsyb1423</Itemsyb>
            <Element1><!-- unbounded -->
               <ElementValue1>ElementValue11070</ElementValue1>
 <ElementLevel>ElementLevel1428</ElementLevel>
               <Elementsyb>Elementsyb1429</Elementsyb>
            </Element1>
         </Item>
         <Item><!-- unbounded -->
            <ItemValue1>Itemvalue123</ItemValue1>
             <ItemLevel>ItemLevel1422</ItemLevel>
            <Itemsyb>Itemsyb1423</Itemsyb>
            <Element1><!-- unbounded -->
               <ElementValue1>ElementValue11070</ElementValue1>
 <ElementLevel>ElementLevel1428</ElementLevel>
               <Elementsyb>Elementsyb1429</Elementsyb>
            </Element1>
         </Item>
         </OrderLines>

         <OrderLines>
         <LineValue1></LineValue1><!-- if LineValue1 is  null then ignore the sequence number(don't increment) -->
         <Linelevel>Linelevel1419</Linelevel>
         <Linesyb>Linesyb1420</Linesyb>
         <Item>
            <ItemValue1>ItemValue11067</ItemValue1>
            <ItemLevel>ItemLevel1422</ItemLevel>
            <Itemsyb>Itemsyb1423</Itemsyb>
            <Element1>
               <ElementValue1>ElementValue11070</ElementValue1>
 <ElementLevel>ElementLevel1425</ElementLevel>
               <Elementsyb>Elementsyb1426</Elementsyb>
            </Element1>
         </Item>
         </OrderLines>

   </OrderHeader>

</process>
```

output:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<process xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/JMS_TEST/JMS_Publish/JMSSendToQueue">
   <OrderHeader>
      <HeaderValue1>1</HeaderValue1><!--sequence number starts from 1 -->
      <OrderLines>
         <LineValue1>2</LineValue1><!-- The LineValue1 is NOT NULL so increment the sequence number by '1'-->
         <Linelevel>Linelevel1419</Linelevel>
         <Linesyb>Linesyb1420</Linesyb>
         <Item><!-- The ItemValue1 is  NULL so don't increment the sequence number by '1' and ignore the ItemValue1-->
         <ItemLevel>ItemLevel1422</ItemLevel>
            <Itemsyb>Itemsyb1423</Itemsyb>
            <Element1>
               <ElementValue1>3</ElementValue1><!-- The ElementValue1 is NOT NULL so increment the sequence number by '1'-->
               <ElementLevel>ElementLevel1428</ElementLevel>
               <Elementsyb>Elementsyb1429</Elementsyb>
            </Element1>
         </Item>
         <Item>
            <ItemValue1>4</ItemValue1><!-- The ItemValue1 is NOT NULL so increment the sequence number by '1'-->
             <ItemLevel>ItemLevel1422</ItemLevel>
            <Itemsyb>Itemsyb1423</Itemsyb>
            <Element1>
               <ElementValue1>5</ElementValue1><!-- The ElementValue1 is NOT NULL so increment the sequence number by '1'-->
               <ElementLevel>ElementLevel1428</ElementLevel>
               <Elementsyb>Elementsyb1429</Elementsyb>
            </Element1>
         </Item>
      </OrderLines>
      <OrderLines>
         <Item>
            <ItemValue1>6</ItemValue1>
            <ItemLevel>ItemLevel1422</ItemLevel>
            <Itemsyb>Itemsyb1423</Itemsyb>
            <Element1>
               <ElementValue1>7</ElementValue1>
               <ElementLevel>ElementLevel1428</ElementLevel>
               <Elementsyb>Elementsyb1429</Elementsyb>
            </Element1>
         </Item>
      </OrderLines>
   </OrderHeader>
   </process>
```

I tried the below xslt it is almost wrking ,but the issue  is not ignoring the sequece number incase of above condition.

xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <process>
      <xsl:for-each select="/process/OrderHeader">
        <xsl:variable name="headerPosition">
          <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="headerVar">
          <xsl:value-of select="
          int(
          count(/process/OrderHeader[position()&lt;$headerPosition]//OrderLines)+
          count(/process/OrderHeader[position()&lt;$headerPosition]//OrderLines//Item)+
          count(/process/OrderHeader[position()&lt;$headerPosition]//OrderLines//Element1)+
          position())"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <OrderHeader>
          <HeaderValue1>
            <xsl:value-of select="$headerVar"/>
          </HeaderValue1>
          <xsl:for-each select="ns1:OrderLines">
            <xsl:variable name="LinePos">
              <xsl:value-of select="int(position())"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="LineVar">
              <xsl:value-of select="int(
              $headerVar+
              count(/process/OrderHeader[position()=$headerPosition]/OrderLines[position()&lt;$LinePos]//Item)+
              count(/process/OrderHeader[position()=$headerPosition]/OrderLines[position()&lt;$LinePos]//Item//Element1)+
              position())"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <OrderLines>
            <xsl:if test="LineValue1!=''">
              <LineValue1>
                <xsl:value-of select="$LineVar"/>
              </LineValue1>
              </xsl:if>

              <xsl:for-each select="ns1:Item">
                <xsl:variable name="ItemPos">
                  <xsl:value-of select="int(position())"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="ItemVar">

                  <xsl:value-of select="int(
              $LineVar+

              count(/process/OrderHeader[position()=$headerPosition]/OrderLines[position()=$LinePos]//Item[position()&lt;$ItemPos]//Element1)+
              position())"/>
                </xsl:variable>


                <Item>
                  <xsl:if test="ItemValue1!=''">
                  <ItemValue1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$ItemVar"/>
                  </ItemValue1>
                  </xsl:if>

                  <xsl:for-each select="Element1">

                    <Element1>
                      <ElementValue1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$ItemVar+position()"/>
                      </ElementValue1>
                    </Element1>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </Item>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </OrderLines>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </OrderHeader>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </process>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I tried the above XSLT,It is giving the sequence number,but fr the above condition case it is not ignoring the sequence number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic instead (I'm saying logic only because I am not sure of the namespaces present in your XML file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="process/OrderHeader/HeaderValue1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(.) + count(preceding::HeaderValue1[.!=''])"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="process/OrderHeader/OrderLines/LineValue1">
        <xsl:if test=". != ''">
            <LineValue1>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(.) + count(preceding::LineValue1[.!='']) + count(preceding::HeaderValue1[.!=''])"/>
            </LineValue1>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="process/OrderHeader/OrderLines/Item/ItemValue1">
    <xsl:if test=".!=''">
        <ItemValue1>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(.) + count(preceding::ElementValue1[.!='']) + count(preceding::ItemValue1[.!='']) + count(preceding::LineValue1[.!='']) + count(preceding::HeaderValue1[.!=''])"/>
        </ItemValue1>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="process/OrderHeader/OrderLines/Item/Element1/ElementValue1">
    <ElementValue1>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(.) + count(preceding::ElementValue1[.!='']) + count(preceding::ItemValue1[.!='']) + count(preceding::LineValue1[.!='']) + count(preceding::HeaderValue1[.!=''])"/>
    </ElementValue1>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```